SSL is required, but the server does not support it Rails with MariaDB
I try to setup my Rails (6.1) server with MariaDB (10.11) but when i want create my database i got error :
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it
Caused by:
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: TLS/SSL error: SSL is required, but the server does not support it

My default my.cnf:
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /usr/local/etc/my.cnf.d

My database.yml:
johndoe_dev: &johndoe_dev
  adapter: mysql2
  database: the_wagon
  pool: 25
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  host: localhost
  timeout: 5000
  username: myuser
  password: password
  encoding: utf8mb4
  collation: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
  variables:
    sql_mode: TRADITIONAL

development:
  <<: *default
  <<: *<%= Rails.env.development? ? "#{ENV["USER"]}_dev" : "ai_dev" %>

I tried multiple solutions like desactivate SSL in database.yml with ssl_mode: :disable or in my.cnf with ssl = 0 but nothing work
I installed mysql2 gem with mariadb-connector-c if it can have a link

which mariadb-connector-c version? If a 3.4.0 it looks like this issue.

I installed 3.4.3 @danblack

MariaDB Connector/C 3.4.x was first shipped together with MariaDB 11.4 (and newer). MariaDB 11.4 always starts with TLS/SSL support, even if you didn't configure it (creating certificates automatically).
MariaDB Connector/C 3.4.x enables peer certificate verification by default, which requires a secure TLS/SSL connection.
Since mysql2 doesn't support enabling or disabling peer certificate verification, the are other possible solutions/workarounds:
Connector/C:

Build Connector/C 3.4.x with cmake option
-DDEFAULT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
Clone and build Connector/C 3.4 branch from github and set environment variable MARIADB_TLS_DISABLE_PEER_VERIFICATION=1 (See CONC-747)
Install latest C/C 3.3
wait for Release of C/C 3.4.4.

MariaDB Server:

Upgrade to 11.4 or newer

Ruby:
Use a configuration file, e.g. ~/.my.cnf with the following group:
[johndoe_dev]
ssl-verify-server-cert=0

and specify the group name when creating the connection:
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host => '127.0.0.1',
  ....
  :default_group => 'johndoe_dev'
)

